# MVC dropdownlist is showing duplicate options

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my Controller I've created a dropdownlist:

```
 ViewBag.Year = new SelectList(db.Inventorys, "InventoryId", "Year");
```

In my View it is written like this:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Year", null, "All Years", new { onchange = "this.form.submit()" })
```

I have many inventory with the same year, so the list has, for example, the year 2010 listed 5 times.

How do I select only unique years using the above example?

Thank you!

Comment: if multiple `InventoryId`'s will match up to a year, what `InventoryId` will you get from each individual year?

Comment: @JonLaMarr  Can you show me an example of where I would insert distinct()?

Comment: @Jonesy I would get two different InventoryIds, as two separate inventory items have the same year. Sorry, I'm not understanding what your point is.

Comment: @JonLaMarr I tried this, but it didn't change anything: ViewBag.Year = new SelectList(db.Inventorys, "InventoryId", "Year").Distinct();

Comment: I mean, you have it set up one-to-one (each year has one ID).  But that's not the case.  So this method won't work to achieve your desired results

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't already, make sure you include Linq...

```
using System.Linq;
```

You will have to do some grouping.

```
var myInventory = from firstList in db.Inventorys
                  group firstList by firstList.Year into newList
                  let m = newList.FirstOrDefault()
                  select m;
```

Then use this...

```
ViewBag.Year = new SelectList(myInventory.ToList(), "InventoryId", "Year");
```